# Android: Cant install my app on Nexus7/10 and other tablets

Tags: android, google-play, nexus-7

I can't install my app from Google Play on Nexus 7. 
It tells me that the device is not supported and in the unsupported devices I see a lot of tablets, even though I can install directly the .apk on the device and it works at native size.

The minSdkVersion is 7, I've tried with targetSdkVersion 8 and 17 and the result is the same.

What I'm doing wrong?

Is it because of any uses-permission?

**UPDATE:**The least of all permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Please include the app's uses-permissions in the question.

Comment: I'd suggest posting the entire manifest, as permissions are only one possible problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is typically due to use permissions in the manifest that aren't declared as not required. (i.e. android:required="false"). In my personal experience, permissions involving cameras are normally the culprit

More information straight from the [developer page:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html)

> If you request a hardware-related permission — CAMERA, for example — Google Play assumes that your application requires the underlying hardware feature and filters the application from devices that do not offer it.
>
> To control filtering, always explicitly declare hardware features in
>    elements, rather than relying on Google Play to
>   "discover" the requirements in  elements. Then, if
>   you want to disable filtering for a particular feature, you can add a
>   android:required="false" attribute to the  declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add some `<uses-feature>`

**IMPORTANT:** everything must be lower case. Initially I've tried with upper case, as in class declaration, but it doesn't work

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
```

`android.hardware.telephony` is enough to make it work on Nexus 7/10 and all those tablets.